# Augmented Matrix and Dimensions

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

So when we have the standard forms of a linear equation system and then we represent it as an augmented matrix, the constant is not included as part of the dimension of the augmented matrix, right?

So, let's say we have two variables (x and y) and three equations. This would be a 3 * 2 matrix?  It would not be a 3 * 3 correct? The constants column does not count?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not correct. For example, consider the system of equations
$$
x + 2y = 3,\\
4x + 5y = 6,\\
7x + 8y = 9.
$$
The matrix equation corresponding to this system is $Ax = b$, where
$$
A = \pmatrix{1 & 2\\4&5\\7&8}, \quad b = \pmatrix{3\\6\\9}.
$$
The augmented matrix associated with this system is
$$
M = [A \mid b] = \left[\begin{array}{cc|c} 1&2&3\\4&5&6\\ 7&8&9 \end{array} \right].
$$
The size of the augmented matrix is $3 \times 3$. The *coefficient matrix* $A$ has size $3 \times 2$.

Comment: Hi Ben. Thanks for the answer. The idea that the augmented matrix and coefficient matrix could be different was one point of confusion. Plus, I was thinking how would that augmented matrix be reduced (R-REF or Gauss-Jordan elimination) and then thought, if the augmented Matrix is 3 * 3, wouldn't that mean that its a square matrix and square matrices tend to have (always?) a main diagonal when reduced? But this doesn't make sense here as you couldn't have a main diagonal unless you reduced the last row constant.

Comment: @ed8484 A possibly helpful statement: note that the system $Ax = b$ will have a solution if and only if the RREF of the augmented matrix $[A \mid b]$ does **not** have a pivot (a first $1$ of any row) in its final column.

Comment: Does the final column include the constant column? As that would mean that X2 was 1.

Comment: @ed8484 Yes, the final column of the augmented matrix is the constant column

Comment: Right. I guess one final unclear thing is, I was taught that if you have a square matrix, you will have a main diagonal ALWAYS. (but these teachers did not include the constant column in the R-REF). So let's say we had a 2 by 2 coefficient matrix but a 2 by 3 augmented. Don't we want a main diagonal for the first two columns?

Comment: With the point being that isn't the OUTCOME/the goal (the R-REF) in reference to the coefficient matrix and not the augmented one?

Comment: @ed8484 First of all, your statement is incorrect: if you have a square matrix, you will not necessarily have a main diagonal of $1$s; we only get that main diagonal when the matrix is invertible. For example, try to find the RREF of 
$$
\pmatrix{1&2\\2&4}.
$$

Comment: @ed8484 Second, it is valid to think of things either in terms of the RREF of the coefficient matrix or in terms of the RREF of the augmented matrix. In the usual presentation, one applies the Gauss Jordan process to the *augmented* matrix until the coefficient matrix is in its RREF. However, there is no reason that we *need* to stop there; we could keep reducing so that the entire augmented matrix is in RREF. An interesting point, however, is that if the system has a solution, then the augmented matrix is already in RREF once the coefficient matrix is done.

Comment: My apologies. I should have written that better. Assuming there is a square matrix, and it is invertible, is it considered a square matrix in its coefficient matrix form? or is the size of it considered when it becomes augmented? The answer seems to be the former? The size, in reference to reducing it, is based on the coefficient matrix?

Comment: A "square matrix" could either refer to a square coefficient matrix or a square augmented matrix; the fact that the matrix is square doesn't tell us anything about the matrix's relation to the linear system being considered. That said, when square matrices are discussed in the context of solving linear systems, it is typically the *coefficient* matrix that is square.

Comment: One additional question. I noticed that when you do R-REF on your example from the beginning, the last row is all 0 (including constant)? What is the interpretation of this?

Comment: @ed8484 One interpretation is that the final equation is redundant. That is, any $(x,y)$ that satisfy the first two equations will automatically satisfy the third equation.